# Model with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

We run two websites, `A` and `B`. Each website has its own table, `_a_` and `_b_` which have exactly the same structure. *Yes, I know it's silly, we'll be rewriting them over the course of this year and next.*

Using Laravel I need to create a model that will hold both tables content. I don't need any kind of `UPDATE` or `INSERT` functionality, I just need to `SELECT` and use `with` to access other model information.

Is this possible with Laravel 4.1? I can individually model each table, but that would make it difficult in the future.

Comment: That is not how ORM works.

Comment: You could create a WebsitesRepository to handle querys and use [union](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#unions) to merge results of both tables

Comment: @dimirc how would you enable this to perform `all`, `find` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by making using the Repository pattern and merging the results of each model into the `get` and `all` functions.